# Open Source iOS projects for learning best coding practices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, coding-style

I have some experience in iOS development (more Java background) and recently I've started to read "Clean Code".

I've noticed that in my iOS projects I have a lot of anti-patterns.

2 most popular recommendations I don't follow properly: **Small methods** and **Small Classes**. 
Then I made small research on GitHub and I din't find project that I can use as example/reference for "Clean Code".

In most of the cases ViewControllers has tens of methods AND they have HUGE methods, like `loadView` where we programmatically build hierarchy of views.

For instance example app from Facebook [wishlist-mobile-sample](https://github.com/facebook/wishlist-mobile-sample) has 1431 lines of code in `HomeViewController`class, and its `loadView` has 170+ lines of code.

Do you have links to the projects you would recommend as a really good coding example?

Answer (score 3):

I dare to dispute that having all classes < 100 lines of code is really a best coding practice ... It all depends on what you use it for, and how important it is to have a class really clean and general. I know quite some pieces of code that are easier to read with hundreds of lines in a class than class-cluttered code with super-mini classes, but hundreds of classes instead ... There is probably a reason lots of projects have bigger classes.

And do you really think that if the statement is "a function should have max. 100 lines of code" that having a function with 130 lines already qualifies for bad coding?!?

**BTW:** The `viewDidLoad` function in the `UICatalog` class from Apple has 42 lines of code - the rest is whitespace and comments - I'd rather not leave those out of your code in order to stay under 100 lines :-)

Comment: We're talking more here about statement "function should have max. 20 lines of code" and having functions with hundreds lines of code. Youre example is 0.3 times difference, in case I'm describing difference is about 10-20 times.

Comment: Well, see my addition - the real code is 42 lines for the Apple example. Objective C is not the most space efficient language, you have to introduce lots of whitespace to keep it readable, especially with the named parameters ...

Comment: I got your point. Anyway, I'm looking for examples of code close to ideal :) Which has small functions which you can easily read. I'm sorry, but I need to scroll this screen few times to read whole method. And this example doesn't have complicated view structure. Use facebook's sample link in the question's body and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm looking for such examples not for Objective-C learning purpose, but for learning how to write better code. My current code isn't too far from Apple example but I wanna progress a bit more :)

Answer (score 2):

I curate the list here [Recommended iOS open source projects](http://www.fantageek.com/691/recommended-ios-open-source-projects/)

For now, they are

1. [Most starred projects on Github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&p=1&q=stars%3A%3E1&s=stars&type=Repositories)
2. [The Open Source iPhone Apps List](http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/35-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-updated-with-10-new-apps)
3. [List of free and open-source iOS applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open-source_iOS_applications)
4. [Sequel Pro](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro)
5. [Anywall](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall) and [AnyPic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic)
6. [Apple sample sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)
7. [Telegram](https://telegram.org/source)
8. [WordPress](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS)
9. [Wikimedia](https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-ios-wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

Apple sample code is the best source for learning clean code..
open source projects can't beat that..

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the purpose of the examples that Apple posts aren't to show best practice all the way through the code, but are to illustrate specific items. Why bother breaking down an init method into lots of smaller chunks (which will take time to do) when you are trying to demonstrate how to make an async networking call.

When writing your code, there's nothing wrong with writing huge methods or huge classes IF they are appropriate for what you are doing, properly commented and don't duplicate anything. It might be that that is just what you have to do.

As a rule of thumb, when writing your code, just think about everything you are trying to do and think if you can break it down into smaller chunks. Think about if *you* were having to do whatever you are writing the code to do and think about how *you* would approach that task.

For example, you might want to write a method that initialises the display. So, you could write one huge method that will do everything. Or, you could break it down in to

```
[self initButtons];
[self initTextEntry];
[self initLabels];
```

Likewise, in the initButtons, you might find that you then write the same code over again to create and init the buttons when it turns out that the only thing that changes is the position of the button and the selector they call when touched. So you can refactor that out

```
button1 = [self createButton:position callback:selector];
button2 = [self createButton:position2 callback:selector2];
```

Just take an iterative approach to what you are writing. Write the code. Once you have a feature working, stop and go back and go through your code and see where you can factor items out, where you have common code that you've put in several times, etc. Use the refactoring tools in XCode.

Develop your own style. It will come with time and the more code you write and refactor, the more easily you will see how things can be split up at the start. When I think of some of the code I wrote 20 years ago, I hope it has been destroyed never to be seen by a compiler again. I've worked on projects written by "professional" developers and there are methods that are huge. For example, I've seen one recently that was 500 (!) lines of code long. And with very few comments.

And remember that having lots of small methods that do very very little combined with a huge amount of classes (even if they are small classes) can also be an anti-pattern.

Answer (score -2):

The three-20 framework from facebook is structured pretty neatly.

http://three20.info/

Source Code: 
https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/src